# php header location vs php_redirect

Tags: php, function, redirect, location

What's the difference between the function `"HTTP_redirect"` and `"header location"` in PHP ?

When must I use the function `"HTTP_redirect"` ?

When must I use the function `"header location"` ?

Look that:
https://php.net/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php --> Manual for HTTP_redirect
https://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php        --> Manual for the function header

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`http_redirect` is basically a helper function, making it easier to use `header location` by allowing you to pass an array for GET data.

Comment: It's a function that does what another function can do, but more easily. Another example of a helper function is [`socket_create_listen()`](http://php.net/socket-create-listen) as a shortcut for `socket_create()`, `socket_bind()` and `socket_listen()`

Answer (score 2):

1. [Header in PHP](https://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

header() function sends a raw HTTP header to a client.

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
?>
```

The above (taken from the PHP documentation) sends a 404 header back to the client.

2. [HTTP Redirect](https://php.net/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php)

Redirect to the given url.

```
<?php
http_redirect("relpath", array("name" => "value"), true, HTTP_REDIRECT_PERM);
?>
```

The above (taken from the PHP documentation) : Output

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.2
Content-Type: text/html
Location: http://www.example.com/curdir/relpath?name=value&PHPSESSID=abc

Redirecting to <a href="http://www.example.com/curdir/relpath?name=value&PHPSESSID=abc">http://www.example.com/curdir/relpath?name=value&PHPSESSID=abc</a>.
```

Answer (score 0):

Header forwards the user to a new page, so PHP reinitializes, it's like a HTML meta redirection, but faster.