# http_redirect() vs header()

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php header location vs php_redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353130/php-header-location-vs-php-redirect)

Throughout the years I've been using PHP I've always redirected to another URL via the `header('Location: example.com')` function. Today while browsing php.net I've noticed there is a function specifically for redirection called `http_redirect()`

Are there any benefits to using `http_redirect()` to `header()` or vice versa?

---

References:

1. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
2. http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php

Comment: Well, for starters, `http_redirect()` is more semantically correct.

Comment: And it is a part of PECL, it is not built into PHP.

Comment: @PurpleCoder I should've taken a closer look!

Comment: Seems to be doing a lot more than a simple redirect. Personally, I think this function is bloated with too many options that you probably won't be using. Also, the documentation points to HttpResponse object for PHP > 5.1, which is a more OO approach. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.httpresponse.php)

Comment: You shouldn't be using relative URLs for redirection...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While `http_redirect()` does some things for you (such as exit, clear output buffers and sends a generic redirection body), it is not a standard function (it comes as part of an extension that's not even a pre-loaded one) and therefore you can't really rely on it being available.